# i need to pass rectangle type of variable to function which is in interface

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class

```
public class QuadTree<T> where T : IHasRect
 {

    private List<T> m_objects = null;                // The objects in this 
    private Rectangle m_rect;                        // The area this  


    // Getters and Setters
    public List<T> Objects { get { return m_objects; } }
    public Rectangle Rect { get {return m_rect; } }  


    public QuadTree(Rectangle rect)
    {
        m_rect = rect;
    }

    public QuadTree(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        m_rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }



      public void Insert(T item)
    {
        // If this quad doesn't intersect the items rectangle, do nothing
        if (!m_rect.IntersectsWith(item.Rect))
            return;

    }


Main Class
static class MainProgram 
{

    static void Main() { 
    QuadTree<IHasRect> qt = new QuadTree<IHasRect>(3,6,6,6);      
    Rectangle rect = qt.Rect;
    Console.WriteLine(rect);
  //  Console.WriteLine(qt.Rect);
   // QuadTree<IHasRect> qt1 = new QuadTree<IHasRect>(rect);
    Rectangle area = new Rectangle(3, 6, 3, 3);
    IHasRect area1 = new QuadTree<IHasRect>(area);
   qt.Insert(area1);
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        List<Item> myList=null;


    Console.WriteLine(myList[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(myList[1]);
    Console.Read();


}}
```

Interface used
         public interface IHasRect
       {
        // The rectangle that defines the object's boundaries.
       Rectangle Rect { get;  }
       }

I need to pass value through qt.Insert()
Do I need separate Class which implementS T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part

```
where T : IHasRect
```

requires that `T` implements the interface IHasRect, which in terms means it must have a getter called Rect that returns a Rectangle.

You will need to have an implementation of that method to any type `T`.

Then, you would use something like

```
public class MyClass : IHasRect
{
    public Rectangle Rect { get {return m_rect; } } 
    // You need some way to set m_rect, and you
    // will probably have other properties as well.
}

QuadTree<MyClass> qt = new QuadTree<MyClass>();
qd.Insert(new MyClass());
Rectangle r = qt.First().Rect;
```

> So what about this function public void Insert(T item) { ... } how to resolve T if i m not implementing interface with Quadtree class

The generic constraint on `QuadTree<T>` says that T must implement IHasRect.  Your own code example shows that:

```
public void Insert(T item)
{
    // If this quad doesn't intersect the items rectangle, do nothing
    if (!m_rect.IntersectsWith(item.Rect))
        return;
}
```

Whatever type T ends up being at compile time, your code knows it will have a Rect getter.

Comment: public Rectangle Rect { get {return m_rect; } }           this is present inside class.

Comment: QuadTree<MyClass> qt = new QuadTree<MyClass>();   In this case how shoul i declare my Quadtree class , do i need to include interface

Comment: Include the interface on MyClass, not on `QuadTree<MyClass>`

Comment: So what about this function    public void Insert(T item)
        { ... }   how to resolve T if i m not implementing interface with Quadtree class

Comment: Your already implement Insert(T item) consistently with the class definition.  I added something to my answer to try and make that more clear.  Beyond that, I'm not sure what you are asking.